# Magento 2 How can I find where/what is making MySQL calls

Tags: magento2, debugging

I have Tideways profiling on my Magento 2 product page which is very slow. The profiling shows that the same 2 queries are run about 60,000 times each. (120,000 queries per page load!)
The queries are:

```
SELECT
  l.product_id,
  l.parent_id
FROM
  catalog_product_super_link AS l
  INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity AS p ON p.entity_id = l.parent_id
  INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity AS e ON e.entity_id = l.product_id
  AND e.required_options = ?
WHERE
  (p.entity_id IN ([..]))
```

And

```
SELECT
  tbl_selection.product_id,
  tbl_selection.parent_product_id,
  [..]
FROM
  catalog_product_bundle_selection AS tbl_selection
  INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity AS e ON e.entity_id = tbl_selection.product_id
  AND e.required_options = ?
  INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity AS parent ON tbl_selection.parent_product_id = parent.entity_id
  INNER JOIN catalog_product_bundle_option AS tbl_option ON tbl_option.option_id = tbl_selection.option_id
WHERE
  (parent.entity_id = :parent_id)
```

These both seem to be coming from core Magento code:

```
vendor\magento\module-bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Selection.php:getChildrenIds()
vendor\magento\module-configurable-product\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable.php:getChildrenIds()
```

I don't have any configurable or bundle products in the catalog.

I have (temporarily) commented out the code in vendor\magento\module-bundle\Model\ResourceModel\Selection.php:getChildrenIds() that calls the queries. and this does stop 1 of the queries running. But commenting out the code in the configurable one causes an error.

How can I find out which block/piece of code is actually calling these?
(Magento 2.3.3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found the cause of the high queries (poor coding in the list.phtml) - I found this by enabling and disabling elements on the page until I saw the page loads improve. Then I studied the relevant block to find the poor code (again enabling and disabling elements until I found the culprit).
It seems there is no quick way to find the issue. You just have to disable things until the issue stops, then debug the one you disabled.
As a quick way of doing this I simply added `return '';` to the top of phtml files.

Answer (score 2):

Enable the default query log, it will log the query with PHP call trace. In that way, you can easily figure out which extension is calling the particular query.

We need to run the below command to enable the log query

> php bin/magento dev:query-log:enable

Once you enabled the query log, whenever you load the page, it will log all the query execution during the page load. You can find the query log in **var/debug/db.log**

Easy for your reference: [image: Enable query log]

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you. This does give me the log. But I still can't work out where/what is calling it? e.g.: TRACE: #1 Magento\Framework\DB\Logger\File[Magento\Framework\DB\Logger\LoggerAbstract]#0000000008d76f9d00000000391af926#->getStats('query', 'SELECT `tbl_sele...', array(':parent_id' => 135056)

Comment: can you please post all the traces for the particular query?

Comment: Thank you. I have now found the cause of the high queries (poor coding in the list.phtml) - I found this by enabling and disabling elements on the page until I saw the page loads improve. Then I studied the relevant block to find the poor code (again enabling and disabling elements until I found the culprit). Thanks